# How to find note by id in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have action in vuex. This action do request to firebase.
I would like to receive record from firebase by 'id'.
But I don't know where I must input this 'id' for searching in database.
I did it here:

```
    const snapshot = await get(child(dbRef, `/users/${uid}/records`), id);
```

but I receive all records, without filtration by 'id'.

```
async fetchRecordById({ dispatch, commit }, id) {
      try {
        let record
        const uid = await dispatch('getUid')
        const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
        const snapshot = await get(child(dbRef, `/users/${uid}/records`), id);
        record = snapshot.val()

        if (record === null) {
          record = {}
        }

        return {...record, id}
      } catch (e) {
        commit('setError', e)
        throw e
      }
    },
```

For version 8 firebase it looks like:

```
const record = (await firebase.database().ref(`/users/${uid}/records`).child(id).once('value')).val() || {}
```

How to integrate in version 9?

Answer (score 1):

The `get()` function only takes one `DatabaseReference` as a parameter but you are also passing the `id`.

Instead, you can specify the path directly in `ref()` function as shown below:

```
console.log(uid, id) // <-- check if values are correct 
const dbRef = ref(getDatabase(), `/users/${uid}/records/${id}`)

const snapshot = await get(dbRef);
console.log(snapshot.val())
```